# Reading all scripts and data files from multiple folders

Tags: r, file-io

I have two folders, `folder1` and `folder2` with around 200 files each that are either `*rda` or `*R`. I want to read all of the files and datasets from the two directories. How can I do that?

Paths for:

```
folder1:  C:\folder1
folder2:  C:\folder2
```

My trial

```
setwd("C:/folder1")
myls <- ls() # do work as this will only list that are already loaded in the system 
setwd("C:/folder2")
myls2 <- ls()
myls  # do work as this will only list that are already loaded in the system
```

I know this is simple question, but I do not have any answer.

Comment: Generallly this will not succeed because *.R files need to be sourced while *.rda files need to be loaded.

Comment: @DWin: That's certainly convention, but I suppose the files could be saved either way. Ram Sharma: are the .R files actual R code? If so, my code is easy to rewrite (simply `source` all .R files and load all `.rda` files)

Comment: @DavidRobinson yes they are actual R codes (with functions)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Since `.rda` requires `load` and `.R` requires `source`, I would do something like this:

```
file.sources = list.files(pattern="*.R")
data.sources = list.files(pattern="*.rda")
sapply(data.sources,load,.GlobalEnv)
sapply(file.sources,source,.GlobalEnv)
```

### Update for reading from multiple folders at once

```
file.sources = list.files(c("C:/folder1", "C:/folder2"), 
                          pattern="*.R$", full.names=TRUE, 
                          ignore.case=TRUE)
data.sources = list.files(c("C:/folder1", "C:/folder2"),
                          pattern="*.rda$", full.names=TRUE, 
                          ignore.case=TRUE)
sapply(data.sources,load,.GlobalEnv)
sapply(file.sources,source,.GlobalEnv)
```

Notice also the use of `$` at the end of the search pattern, to make sure it matches only, say, a `.R` at the end of a line, and the use of `ignore.case` in case some of the files are named, say, `script.r`.

Comment: You should use `TRUE` instead of `T` for the `full.names` and the `ignore.case` argument. Just think about `T <- FALSE` (which is totally legal) before your script. Furthermore, `*.` seems to be the wrong regular expression (as `.` is  a special character, see `?regex`). What you probably want is `\\.rda$` or `\\.R$`.

Comment: Can I run the multiple scripts simultaneously?

Answer (score 6):

```
for (f in list.files(pattern="*.R")) {
    source(f)
}
for (f in list.files(pattern="*.rda")) {
    load(f)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `tidyverse` instead, you could use the `map` function to simplify:

```
my_path <- c("/path/to/files/")             # set your path
source_files <- list.files(my_path, "*.R$")  # locate all .R files
map(paste0(my_path, source_files), source)  # source all your R scripts!
```

Comment: Your regular expression will evaluate `TRUE` to anything with a capital `R` in it. E.g. `VIRUS.exe` or `NotAnRobject.notR`. You want `\\.R$`. `list.files` also does not need a full match.